# How to adapt this vba code to only copy from first worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to change the following code below to only copy the first worksheet, rather than every worksheet. I am a complete noob at VBA, so I'm not really sure

```
 Sub MergeExcelFiles()
    Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
    Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
    Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook

    fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel 
    Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel 
    files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)

    If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then

        If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
            countFiles = 0
            countSheets = 0

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

            Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook

            For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
                countFiles = countFiles + 1

                Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)

                For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                    countSheets = countSheets + 1
                    wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
                Next

                wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

            Next

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

            MsgBox "Processed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If
End Sub
```

I thought I could just change

```
wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
```

to

```
wksCurSheet(1).Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
```

but clearly that doesnt work

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the For-Next loop - that is what is operating on every sheet. If you just want he first sheet copied use

```
wbkSrcBook.Sheets(1).Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
```